# Algoritmo de intercambio de nodos de una lista enlazada a través de su índice

Tags: c++, lista, loops

Me trae un ejercicio resuelto que no consigo entender, el caso es que COMPILA y funciona, pero de qué me sirve si no entiendo el código. Según lo que entiendo, intercambia el valor del atributo data del nodo i-ésimo (nodo en la posición i de la lista) con el nodo j-ésimo.

este es el código que no entiendo:

```
template <class T>
void dll_t<T>::swap(const int i, const int j)
{ assert(i < j);
  assert(i <= sz_);
  assert(j <= sz_);
  int k = 0; 
  dll_node_t<T> *node_i = get_head(), *node_j = NULL; // por qué node_j se inicia a NULL? su contenido tiene que apuntar a algo porque ese algo se va intercambiar con node_i no?
  while (++k < i) node_i = node_i->get_next(); // ¿con que fin se declara k? y luego por qué ++k en vez de ++k

  node_j = node_i->get_next();// a partir de aqui abajo no entiendo nada
  while (++k < j) node_j = node_j->get_next();

  T temp = node_i->get_data();
  node_i->set_data(node_j->get_data());
  node_j->set_data(temp);
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comenté en otras ocasiones, tengo la sensación que te faltan por aprender conceptos básicos de C++ antes de abordar los ejercicios que has mostrado en la página. Voy a intentar abordar tus dudas pero sería aconsejable que estudiaras algunos fundamentos de C++.

> ```
> /* por qué node_j se inicia a NULL? su contenido tiene que apuntar a algo
>    porque ese algo se va intercambiar con node_i no? */
> dll_node_t<T> *node_i = get_head(), *node_j = NULL;
> ```

Es una buena costumbre inicializar las variables cuando se declaran, se hace apuntar el nodo a `NULL` (aunque lo aconsejable sería `nullptr`) porque aún no se sabe que valor asignarle; se puede ver unas líneas más abajo que se le asigna valor (`node_j = node_i->get_next();`) así que el valor inicial no es usado.

> ```
> // ¿con que fin se declara k? y luego por qué ++k en vez de ++k
> while (++k < i) node_i = node_i->get_next();
> ```

`k` se declara como variable contador, por lo que veo en el código, dicha variable debe obtener como valor los índices de los nodos que la lista contiene, por ello se compara contra los índices de los nodos a intercambiar (`i` y `j`). Respecto a usar el pre-incremento en dicha variable de contador, es simplemente por eficiencia (puedes leer los detalles completos de dicha eficiencia en este [artículo que compara pre-operar con post-operar](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/)).

---

Lo que hace el código que has enlazado es:

1. Crea dos punteros a nodo (`node_j` y `node_i`).

   ```
   dll_node_t<T> *node_i = get_head(), *node_j = NULL;
   ```
2. Recorre los nodos desde el inicio de la lista (`get_head()`) para hacer que los punteros a nodo apunten a los nodos `i`ésimo y `j`ésimo.

   ```
   while (++k < i) node_i = node_i->get_next();
   while (++k < j) node_j = node_j->get_next();
   ```
3. Intercambia el valor de los nodos usando un nodo auxiliar (`temp`) de intercambio.

   ```
   T temp = node_i->get_data();
   node_i->set_data(node_j->get_data());
   node_j->set_data(temp);
   ```

[image]